# Why is django test client throwing away my extra headers

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I'm trying to test a view that makes use of some headers. In my test code I have something like this:

```
headers = {'X-Github-Event': 'pull_request'}
body = {useful stuff}
url = reverse(my_view)
```

I've tried making requests to my view using all possible combinations of the following clients and post calls:

```
client = Client(extra=headers)        
client = APIClient(headers=headers)
client = APIClient(extra=headers)

response = client.post(url, data=body, format="json", headers=headers)
response = client.post(url, data=body, format="json", extra=headers)
```

My view effectively looks like this:

```
@api_view(["POST", "GET"])
def github_webhook(request):
    print(request.headers)
```

My `X-Github-Event` header is never printed out by my view when it is called from my test code.

If I run runserver and send a request to that endpoint then the headers work perfectlty fine. It's just the test code that is broken.

What am I missing here? How can I set the headers for my tests?

Comment: I'm having the same issue here. Did you sort it out?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the following snippet will help you:

```py
import json
from django.test import TestCase
from rest_framework.test import APIClient


class FooTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.client = APIClient(ACCEPT='application/json')

    def test_foo(self):
        headers = {"ACCEPT": "application/json", 'HTTP_X_GITHUB_EVENT': 'pull_request'}
        url = reverse(my_view)
        payload = json.dumps(body)
        response = self.client.post(url, data=payload, content_type='application/json', **headers)
```